# mmap fails for newly created file

Tags: c, mmap

My program creates a file using

```
HANDLE_ERROR(fd = open(path/to/file,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0640)))
```

Mapped it

```
uint8_t *output_file_addr = (uint8_t *)mmap ( NULL, size , PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 )
if(output_dic_addr == MAP_FAILED){  
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

The mmap responds with **Permission denied**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by a**llocating space** for file using **posix_fallocate**(...).

I thought the mmap will do the allocation as well (wrong judgment)

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct. I think the perception that allocation was needed was due to `posix_fallocate` returning a properly aligned address. When using `mmap`, you must insure the `offset` parameter must be a multiple of the page size as returned by `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`. See [man 2 mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Comment: In my case, i am starting from the beginning of the file, so i set the offset to 0. However i had also tried sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) as the last argument which results in the same "bus error" which means that i am writing outside the file.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't expect a `"bus error"` that usually indicates a pointer containing an address outside of a valid range (like inadvertently assigning `pointer = 5;` instead of `*pointer = 5;`). Your `0` will be fine starting at the beginning of file. As long as OP's `size` parameter is correct he shouldn't have to allocate. Most likely `path/to/file` is pointing somewhere the user lacks write permission

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to create a write only mapping on typical hardware and the file has been opened without read permission.

Comment: Have also tried with flag"O_RDWR|O_CREAT", but it doesn't allow me to write without using system level allocate(..)